# Send text to the text-box of ClientName, when click on Addmore button creates new Textbox with same id and class-name

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Dynamically created text-box on add button click with same id and class-name not able to send text second/third text-box.

```
List<WebElement> clientidtxt = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[contains(.,'Client ID')]/following::input[@id='CId']"));
for (WebElement webElement1 : clientidtxt)
{
    if(!clientidtxt.isEmpty())
    {
        clientId.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        clientId.sendKeys(uuid);
        System.out.println(webElement1.getText());
    }
}
```

I have already send text to first text-box but not able to send to the second or third ....

Comment: what is clientId, to which you send keys? Dont see that it is iterated in your loop.

Comment: Actually Client Id is label just before the text-box, so just tried to use following in xpath.   Initially using this, List<WebElement> clientidtxt= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@id='ClientId']"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is kinda confusing.

1. You are looping through a list of web elements but inside you check to see if the list is empty... it can't be if you are looping through the list so that part can be removed.
2. You are using a foreach but you aren't actually using `webElement1` but instead are referencing `clientId` which isn't declared in the code you posted.

I've updated the code with a best guess. Try this and see if it's what you are looking for.

```
List<WebElement> clientidtxt = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[contains(.,'Client ID')]/following::input[@id='CId']"));
for (WebElement webElement1 : clientidtxt)
{
        webElement1.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER); // What's this for? Can this be removed?
        webElement1.sendKeys(uuid);
        System.out.println(webElement1.getText()); // if webElement1 is an INPUT, this needs to be webElement1.getAttribute("value") to return what the INPUT contains
}
```

Comment: If clientidtxt  has text then it should add text to another textbox which is empty

Comment: OK. You really need to add some more explanation in your question as to what you are attempting to do and give examples for at least 2-3 loops.

Comment: Actually, ClientID is textbox by default one is present and user can add client details, but if user wants to add multiple client then by click on AddmoreClient button, every time new Textbox will be added and user can add the Client. If Client is already present then user can click on AddmoreClient  button to add more clients.

Comment: You need to edit your question and add these details... not continue to add them in comments. You want future readers to only have to read your question and not read every comment under the question and every answer to get all the necessary information to answer the question.

Comment: Just changed the summary pls check is it clear now.

Comment: You haven't added ANY of the two comments that you just posted under my question into your question. You also haven't provided the examples that I asked for above.

Comment: Client Textbox display by default, u can send text to it. But if user wants more client to then user will click on Add more button, then new textbox of clientname will be create with same id and name. User wants to send the text each clientname whenever new clientname is added